# jQuery, can;t change the fieldn value

Tags: jquery

I use Liquid Slider 2  plugin. I had a form in one of the tabs. I need to change the value of one filed via jquery on document ready. It does not change the value. When I console.log the value I get correct values.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            console.log($("#ttt").val());
            $("#ttt").val("test");
            console.log($("#ttt").val());
        });
```

Comment: That means the value gets changed fine but doesn't show there right away, could be due to some UI enhancements. Try any refresh method after changing the value on that field

Comment: It looks right so there isn't enough code to reproduce this. If you can create a jsfiddle that would be useful.

Comment: Check the plugin documentation to see if it provides its own method for changing the value.

Answer (score 0):

The slider clones the first and last panels to allow for a continuous effect. You just have to make sure you are updating and validating both the clone and the original. I thought about implementing this in the slider, but it would bulk up the code for just a few use cases.

I might end up creating an extension for this though, as it does come up more often than other issues.